# Confusion regarding a passage in the "Kinds and some type-foo" section of learnyouahaskell.com

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell noob who's working his way through the wonderful "Learn You A Haskell For Great Good". This question is related to a passage in the section called ["Kinds and some type-foo"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo) in chapter 8. The passage that reads:

*"Making **Frank** an instance of **Tofu** is pretty simple. We see that **tofu** takes a **j a** (so an example type of that form would be **Maybe Int**) and returns a **t a j**. So if we replace **Frank** with **j**, the result type would be **Frank Int Maybe**."*

This has me somewhat befuddled. In my mind the last sentence should read:

*"So if we replace **t** with **Frank**, the result type would be **Frank Int Maybe**."*

Any explanation as to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm with @ehird, it is an error of the book. You should warn the author about it. His email address is on the homepage of the book.

Comment: @Riccardo I've sent him an email. Thanks for your response.

Comment: The error is still there, btw. I don't understand what the effort is in correcting such an obvious error...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not going wrong at all. It's an error in the book. Your proposed sentence is correct.