# What mean type `a -> m b` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Example - function `runKleisli` from Haskell base module

```
newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli { runKleisli :: a -> m b }
```

That means `runKleisli` have 1 argument with type `a` and must return function `m`, which have 1 argument `b`?

Comment: It means `m` is a type of *kind* `* -> *`; that is, `m` is a *type constructor* that accepts a single argument, like `Maybe` or `Either String`.

Comment: @AlexisKing, Thanks, you can post it as answer and I will accept it

Comment: It is similar to how generics work in Java or C#, or to how templates work in C++. In Java for example the function's signature would be something like `M<B> runKleisli(A a)`. This isn't an exact analogy though, since the Haskell signature you provided is a lot more generic than the Java signature I gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means `m` is a type of *kind* `* -> *`; that is, `m` is a *type constructor* that accepts a single argument, like `Maybe` or `Either String`. When you instantiate `Kleisli` and perform the substitution yourself, you can see how this works out.

For example, consider something like `Kleisli Maybe String Integer`. The substituted type of `runKleisli` would be `String -> Maybe Integer`, and you can see how the `m` is being used as a type constructor.

For more information about kinds in Haskell, see [What exactly is the kind "*" in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27095011/465378).

Comment: I just find out that I don't quite understand, I don't know monads for now, so can you answer, function `m` must **return** or **accept as argument** something with type `b`?

Comment: Question in context of this function `(*>) :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)` from [book of Anton Kholomiov page 86](https://anton-k.github.io/ru-haskell-book/files/ru-haskell-book.pdf))

Comment: @bjornmelgaard `m` is not (necessarily) a function; it is just a type constructor. In the example I gave in my answer, `Kleisli Maybe String Integer` is just a simple wrapper around `String -> Maybe Integer`. Nothing more, nothing less. The `m` in that example is `Maybe`, which is obviously not a function.

Comment: Ok, `m b` means constructor and only constructor(?). Therefore in `class Category cat where \ id :: cat a a \ (>>) :: cat a b -> cat b c -> cat a c` cat is  a constructor and only constructor with 2 arg too?

Comment: @bjornmelgaard Neither. When you write `Maybe Integer` is `Maybe` returning or accepting as argument something with type `Integer`? Answer: The question makes no sense because `Maybe` is not a function.